# jQuery-File-Upload change path dynamically

Tags: jquery

I'm using the Blueimp jQuery file upload tool. How can I dynamically change folder for uploads?

I've tried this way:

UploadHandler.php

```
$dirPath = $_POST['dirpath'];
            'upload_dir' => '../../mydir/'.$dirPath,
            'upload_url' => '../../mydir/'.$dirPath,
```

HTML with Form:

```
<input type="text" name="dirpath" value="123"/>
```

Comment: _"I'm using the Blueimp jQuery file upload tool. How can I dynamically change folder for uploads?"_ , _"HTML with Form"_ appear to be `input type="text"` element ?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a field for the folder name

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an object containing property "dirpath" , `File` object , at `change` event , utilize `$.post()` to send object containing "dirpath" , `File` object to `php` file

```js
$("form").on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var res = {
    "dirpath": $("input[type=text]", this).val(),
    "file": e.target.files
  };
  // $.post(url, res);
  console.log(res)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="dirpath" value="123" />
  <input type="file" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Maybe someone does come in handy

HTML

```
<textarea type="text" name="dirpath">123</textarea>
```

UploadHandler.php

```
        'upload_dir' => '../../'.$dirPath = $_POST['dirpath'].'/',
        'upload_url' => '../../'.$dirPath = $_POST['dirpath'].'/',
```

And if u need to rename uploaded file u can also use this:

```
protected function trim_file_name($file_path, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range) {
        $name = $_POST['dirpath'];

        return $name;
    }
```